# JQuery siblings(). add class only to clicked column in any row

Tags: jquery, siblings

its working for each row. how use it for only one  at once from any row?
add class only to clicked column in any row and all other td in all tr class should be empty. 
pls help

```
$('td').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('td').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5QsCy/3/

Comment: If you will use sibling of current td then it will return only one td that is its sibling.this is the reason your code is not working. every td in your code have one td sibling other td are its cousin not sibling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `active` class from all `td` element's. As of now you are removing the class only from sibling `td` elements.

```
$('td').click(function(){
    $('td.active').removeClass('active'); //Remove active class from all td
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xdfoydy8/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply remove the `active` class on all `td` before setting it to the new cell?

```js
$('td').click(function(){
    $('td').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>COL</td>
    <td>COL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>COL</td>
    <td>COL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>COL</td>
    <td>COL</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#xyz td').click(function(){
    $("#xyz").find('td').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

HTML:-

```
 <table id="xyz">
    <tr><td>COL</td><td>COL</td></tr>
    <tr><td>COL</td><td>COL</td></tr>
    <tr><td>COL</td><td>COL</td></tr>
    <table>
```

CSS:-

```
.active {border:solid 1px red;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5QsCy/9/)

Comment: Can please suggest me what is problem with this code